# Do I have enough room to thread 4/3 cable with ground through my basement?

Tags: wiring, subpanel, cables

I'm planning a partial basement renovation, including installing a subpanel to supply 70A, requiring 4 AWG copper wire.  I'd like to avoid installing conduit, so I hope to use 3-strand + ground Romex.

I haven't worked with 4/3 Romex before, but I imagine it will be quite stiff and difficult to thread through studs.  From what I've read, the diameter of the cable is roughly 0.8 inches, so I know that I have enough room for the required bend radius.  And the gutters of my panel give me enough room inside once I'm working with individual conductors.

The main panel I will be feeding from is in a narrow hall, so I couldn't get a straight-on photo.  Instead, below is a photo plus a diagram showing the route I would like to use for the cable.  I imagine that threading the cable through the two studs below the panel is going to be difficult.  Does the route shown seem realistic?

[image: Photo of panel and cuts in lath & plaster]

In the drawing below, cuts in lath & plaster have a bold outline and the studs are 8 inches apart, except for the space where the panel is (15 inches). The space below the panel, between the panel and the closet, is 5 inches high. Once I'm in the unfinished part of the basement, there is lots of room to work so that's not shown.

It's mostly threading through the two studs below that panel that I have doubts about. I have no qualms about removing more lath and plaster above the bottom opening if that would help.

[image: Route for 4/3 + Ground Romex]

Comment: Is there any going straight down behind(maybe in) the closet?  4 gauge is quite stiff and needs help to bend, unlike 14/12 gauge that will bend easy.  The holes in the studs should be okay.

Comment: @crip659 That's a good idea, but the closet won't do (for reasons I don't have the stamina to go into). Although, you did get me thinking of different options.  Maybe I will remove all the lath and plaster above the bottom opening, so that the two openings are connected.  Then notch the studs instead of drilling them. That way I can feed the cable up from below, then sort of "pre-bend" the cable before sliding it into place.

Comment: You're never (as an amateur, like myself) going to get a 4/3 cable to take that vertical to horizontal bend without a *lot* more working room than you have opened up there. I'd estimate that you'll need to open up that entire stud-bay from where you've made the small hole at the bottom up to the level of your panel.